# Echo and Cat output problem

Tags: command-line, bash, cat, echo

I'm trying to run this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in /home/dima/Downloads/dir/*
do
  if [ -f "$file" ]
  then
    echo "SSS::################====================#####################" >> allfiles.txt
    cat $file >> allfiles.txt
    echo "################====================#####################" >> allfiles.txt
  fi
done
```

It works but strings that echo printed can be seen only in the end of file when I need them between the outputs of "cat". How to fix that?

Comment: You probably have a lot of binary files that cat just skips, but the echos still print.

Comment: please indent code next time on your own

Comment: @ubfan1 why would cat skip binary files? The `-f` test returns true for them, so the `cat` will run so why would they be skipped?

Comment: Zero length files are still binary, right? ;^O

Comment: @Melvil do you have read access to all these files?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour. What version of Ubuntu are you using? Is the code sample you posted exactly the same as the code you're running on your machine? Could you please add an example of expected output and actual output?

Comment: @ubfan1 yes, 0-length files or, more likely, no-read-access files would cause something like this. But not binary ones. Cat can happily cat binary files, that's one of its main reasons for existing, after all.